# Mixing futures and vectors in a for comprehension

Tags: scala, future

I'd like to iterate over a vector that I get from a future.  I'd like the following to work, but it gives a type mismatch compiler error on the `user <- usersToReview` line.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Main3 {
  var counter = 0

  val fUsersToReview: Future[Vector[String]] = Future {Vector("u1", "u2", "u3")}

  def doIt(user: String): Future[Int] = {
    counter = counter + 1
    Future.successful(counter)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val result:Future[Vector[Int]] = for {
      usersToReview ← fUsersToReview
      user ← usersToReview
      msg_id ← doIt(user)
    } yield {
      msg_id
    }

    println(Await.result(result, 1.second))
  }
}
```

The following works, but seems very clunky.  Suggestions on how to improve this?

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val result:Future[Vector[Int]] = (for {
      usersToReview ← fUsersToReview
    } yield {

      Future.sequence(
        for (u ← usersToReview) yield {
          doIt(u)
        }
      )
    }).flatMap(identity)

    println(Await.result(result, 1.second))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the insights from thinking about adrice727's answer, I've got a solution to the problem.  It involves refactoring `doIt` to take the vector. 
 By shifting the handling of the vector to `doIt`, the vector comes out of the for-comprehension.  Once it handles only futures, it works as expected.

I had simplified my original post a bit, so the following includes one more level in the for-comprehension and has `doIt` actually do something with the data it's passed.  The background on this is that `fMaintainers`, `fUsersToReview`, and `doIt` are all acting on a database.

```
val fMaintainers: Future[Vector[String]] = Future {Vector("m1", "m2", "m3")}

val fUsersToReview: Future[Vector[String]] = Future {Vector("u1", "u2", "u3")}

def doIt(users: Vector[String], maintainers: Vector[String]): Future[Vector[(String, String)]] = {
  Future.sequence(for (u ← users) yield {
    Future.successful((u, maintainers.head))
  })
}

val result: Future[Vector[(String, String)]] = for {
  maintainers ← fMaintainers
  usersToReview ← fUsersToReview
  msg_id ← doIt(usersToReview, maintainers)
} yield {
  msg_id
}

println(Await.result(result, 1.second))
```

Finally, following up on adrice727's suggestion that sometimes for-comprehensions aren't the right tool, here it is with maps:

```
val result:Future[Vector[(String, String)]] = 
      fMaintainers.flatMap { m ⇒ fUsersToReview.flatMap { u ⇒ doIt(u, m) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one instance where it's probably cleaner to not use a `for-comprehension` and instead just use `map`:

```
val result: Future[Vector[Int]] = fUsersToReview.map(_.map(doIt(_)))
```

For things like `Option` and `Either`, you can use monad transformers like [OptionT](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) and [EitherT](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html), but there isn't anything for `Vector`.

Comment: This is lovely except that doit returns a Future.  So the return type of this solution is actually Future[Vector[Future[Int]]].

I think what I've learned is that the metaphor of a for-comprehension being like a nested loop breaks down.  A nested loop can iterate over integers in one loop and characters in another, but with for-comprehensions you need to choose the type and be consistent.  If you can't do that, break out the maps and flatMaps  (or look for ways to convert your types).